# How to add multiple hashtag when sharing Content on Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, hashtag, facebook-share

I am using Facebook share in my app. I want to add multiple hashtags with my shared content. I got succeed in adding one hashtag but I need to add multiple hashtags. This is the code I have used so far:

```
            FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
            dialog.fromViewController = self;
            FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
            content.contentTitle = APP_NAME;
            content.contentDescription = text;

            if ([arrAllEvents count]>0) {

                content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[arrAllEvents valueForKey:@"flyer_image"] objectAtIndex:index1]];
            }
            content.contentURL = url;

            NSString *strHashtag =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"#Book",@"#Crazy"];
            content.hashtag = [FBSDKHashtag hashtagWithString:@"#Crazy"];

            dialog.shareContent = content;
            dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb;
            [dialog show];
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can add only one; that is a deliberate limitation to stop apps from getting too spammy with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, FB has updated their [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/overview/). You can only have **1 Hashtag**.